# NameError: name 'a' is not defined. using variable from another function inside the same class

Tags: python

I'm doing this BlackJack program and when I ran it, Python tells me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    c2.bj_value()
  File "/Users/xuanruizhang/Desktop/lab_class_design.py", line 47, in bj_value
    s = PlayingCard(a,b)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

So the problem is with the function bj_value(self). I want to return corresponding value of the rank in the **init** function.
For example: If c2 = PlayingCard(11, "c"), then c2.bj_value() should return 10.

```
class PlayingCard:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        if rank == 1:
            self.rank = "Ace"
        elif rank == (2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10):
            self.rank = rank
        elif rank == 11:
            self.rank = "Jack"
        elif rank == 12:
            self.rank = "Queen"
        elif rank == 13:
            self.rank = "King"
        if suit == "h":
            self.suit = "Hearts"
        elif suit == "s":
            self.suit = "Spades"
        elif suit == "c":
            self.suit = "Clubs"
        elif suit == "d":
            self.suit = "Diamonds"

    def get_rank(self):
        if self.rank == (2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10):
            return self.rank
        elif self.rank == "Ace":
            return 1
        elif self.rank == "Jack":
            return 11
        elif self.rank == "Queen":
            return 12
        elif self.rank == "King":
            return 13


    def get_suit(self):
        if self.suit == "Hearts":
            return "h"
        elif self.suit == "Jack":
            return "j"
        elif self.suit == "Clubs":
            return "c"
        elif self.suit == "Diamonds":
            return "d"


    def bj_value(self):
        s = PlayingCard(a, b)
        if s.a == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10:
            return s.a
        elif s.a == 11 or 12 or 13:
            return 10



    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s of %s' % (self.rank, self.suit)

    def main():

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `rank == (2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10)` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: As @wim suggested, you should do something like `if rank in range(2,11)`

Comment: You might need to review a tutorial on classes and scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to instantiate a new class. Store the ORIGINAL rank value as a variable (you should rename the variable storing the name values Jack, Queen, etc. Access self.rank within the bj_value function:

```
class PlayingCard:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank

        if rank == 1:
            self.card = "Ace"
        elif rank in range(2, 11):
            self.card = str(rank)
        elif rank == 11:
            self.card = "Jack"
        elif rank == 12:
            self.card = "Queen"
        elif rank == 13:
            self.card = "King"
        if suit == "h":
            self.suit = "Hearts"
        elif suit == "s":
            self.suit = "Spades"
        elif suit == "c":
            self.suit = "Clubs"
        elif suit == "d":
            self.suit = "Diamonds"

....

    def bj_value(self):
        if self.rank in range(1,11):
            return self.rank
        elif self.rank in range(11,14):
            return 10
```

Comment: Got it! But could you tell me why this works? Thank you so much!

Comment: So your original error is self explanatory from the error message. You used a variable a that hadn't been defined anywhere. The get_rank is totally redundant if you just store the original rank value inside __init__. You can then access that stored value in other methods defined within the class.

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html